# spring WS need wrap request properties with "request" in old WS contract

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need consume one soup web service from one WSDL file. I want use `spring WS` and `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to solve this. The WS server may use one old SOAP contract. I find something like `<soap:operation soapAction="" style="rpc"/>` in the WSDL file. The WSDL file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"     xmlns:tns="http://impl.sub.xxx.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"     name="hahaPaymentWSImpl" targetNamespace="http://impl.sub.xxx.com/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://impl.sub.xxx.com/" targetNamespace="http://impl.sub.xxx.com/" version="1.0">

  <xs:complexType name="singlePaymentRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="accountName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="singlePaymentResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="amount" type="xs:double"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>

  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="singlePayment">
    <wsdl:part name="request" type="tns:singlePaymentRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="singlePaymentResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="return" type="tns:singlePaymentResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="hahaPaymentWS">
    <wsdl:operation name="singlePayment">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:singlePayment" name="singlePayment">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:singlePaymentResponse" name="singlePaymentResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="hahaPaymentWSImplSoapBinding" type="tns:hahaPaymentWS">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="singlePayment">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="rpc"/>
      <wsdl:input name="singlePayment">
        <soap:body namespace="http://impl.sub.xxx.com/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="singlePaymentResponse">
        <soap:body namespace="http://impl.sub.xxx.com/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="hahaPaymentWSImpl">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:hahaPaymentWSImplSoapBinding" name="hahaPaymentWSPort">
      <soap:address location="http://999.00.837.212:8888/services/hahaPaymentWS"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

First time, `maven-jaxb2-plugin` auto generate the Java beans from the WSDL file. But then don't have `@XmlRootElement` tag. So I manually warp `<xs:complexType>` with `<xs:element>` in WSDL file. And it works.

Then, I send request to the server. It tell me `Found element accountName but could not find matching RPC/Literal part`. The request in log like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns3:singlePayment xmlns:ns3="http://impl.sub.xxx.com/">
         <accountName>xxx</accountName>
      </ns3:singlePayment>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I find `soupUI` can work, just because `soupUI` wrap the request properties with `<request>` tag:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns3:singlePayment xmlns:ns3="http://impl.sub.xxx.com/">
<request>
         <accountName>xxx</accountName>
</request>
      </ns3:singlePayment>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to know is this one issue of server contract? How can I easily solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`wsimport` tool in JDK save me.
Step 1, generate java files:

```
wsimport -keep -verbose http://xxxx/xxx.wsdl
```

Step 2, copy files to project and invoke:

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory  = new ObjectFactory();
SinglePaymentRequest request = objectFactory.createSinglePaymentRequest();
request.setAccountFlag("0");
hahaPaymentWS hahaPaymentWS = new hahaPaymentWSImpl().gethahaPaymentWSPort();
SinglePaymentResponse response = hahaPaymentWS.singlePayment(request);
System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(response));
```

I think `spring WS` and `maven-jaxb2-plugin` have compatibility issue with old SOAP contract.